# Evaluating the indefinite integral $\int\frac{\sec x\tan x}{\sqrt {e^{\sec x}}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function, indefinite-integrals

> $$\int\frac{\sec x\tan x}{\sqrt {e^{\sec x}}} dx$$

I let $u=\sec x$ and I already get its derivative and get $\sec x \tan x$ but I'm confused on assembling it. I get the derivative of the square root of $\sec x$. will it double my square root?

Answer (score 6):

If you set $u = \sec x$, then like you say, $du = \sec x \tan x \,dx$, and so the integral becomes
$$\int\frac{du}{\sqrt{e^u}} .$$
Can you rewrite the integrand in a more standard way and so recognize the integral as an elementary one?

Comment: do you think its necessary to let u secx including the sqrt?

Comment: @Boruto What do you mean "including the sqrt"? If the square root bothers you, just remember that $$\sqrt{e^{\sec(x)}}=e^{\frac{1}{2}\cdot\sec(x)}$$ and either use $u=(1/2)\sec(x)$ or do the above substitution and continue equivalently.

Comment: @Boruto I'm not quite sure what you mean. Does userSeventeen's comment address your question? If not, perhaps you can rephrase it?